# Date validation startdate to from date

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

In jquery I'm trying to validate the dates,but my date field is considered as Monthly if falls below 12..

```
test data:
                  dd/mm/yyyy
 from date Value :07/03/2013
 to date  value  :05/06/2013
```

Javascript:

```
var startdatevalue = $('#txtFromDate').val();
var Todatevalue = $('#txtToDate').val();
if (Todatevalue < startdatevalue) {
    alert("To Date should be greater than From Date.");
    $('#txtToDate').focus();
    return false;
}
```

while comapring the condition is setting true,which is false in my scenario.To date is greater.
Quick solution will help....

Comment: Convert the strings to `Date` before comparing them. Or move the year to the front, so it's `2013/07/03` and `2013/05/06`.

Comment: I suggest u to use jquery.validate.js... Has a greater capability of various types of validation

Comment: If you use datepicker of jQueryUI,use `$.datepicker.parseDate(format, string)` to convert your date values into a javascript Date object, you can then compare the dates using the standard < and >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var startdatevalue = "07/03/2013".split('/');
var todatevalue = "05/06/2013".split('/');
var t=Date.parse(todatevalue[2]+"/"+todatevalue[1]+"/"+todatevalue[0]);
var f=Date.parse(startdatevalue[2]+"/"+startdatevalue[1]+"/"+startdatevalue[0]);
if (f > t) {
 console.log("here");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LdKRF/

Although do take a look into  http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery datepicker (jquery UI) and perform the following

```
var startDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#txtFromDate').val());
var endDate= $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#txtToDate').val());
```

then perform your checn on startDate and endDate

Comment: restricted to use kendo controls as requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (new Date(Todatevalue).getTime() > new Date(startdatevalue).getTime()){
      ---Things To do----
}
```

Comment: Hi, tried this but still the same problem its taking the date as month if date is lower than 12.

Comment: You just need to set your date format to dd/mm/yyyy because by default the date format is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: But javascript is client code and you can't force your website visitors to set the PCs date format to dd/MM/yyyy, this is a code weakness you better solve the problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
   RegEx ;):

```
var dateString = "30/08/2013";
var reggie = /(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})/;
var dateArray = reggie.exec(dateString); 
var dateObject = new Date(
    (+dateArray[3]),
    (+dateArray[2])-1, // Note that month starts at 0!
    (+dateArray[1]),
    0,
    0,
    0
);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
var dt = '30/08/2013'.split('/');

var dateObject = new Date(dt[0], dt[1], dt[2], 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using moment.js in order to do operations with dates. Standard javascript date tools are a little bit poor.
Check the library here:
http://momentjs.com/